# Speed: Saved Objects vs Database

Tags: database, object

I am designing a dynamic site for some form of weather data, which I need to scrape to get the data, as its always changing. I am interested in knowing if its faster to use a database like sqlite or to save objects ,reloading them whenever needed. Both options will hold the scraped data.

Likely will use Python or Ruby, haven't decided yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on a huge number of factors.

If you need to query the data, and search through it, it's likely that using a database will be more efficient.  They are highly optimized for this type of operation.

If, however, you're purely just trying to dump and reload a bunch of memory, it could be faster to save it directly to a file.

That being said, I'd look at how you're going to use the data, and choose the method that makes the most sense for your application.  I would not base this on speed, as, unless you're saving a huge amount of data, the speed of saving the data will likely not be a real performance bottleneck.